# why there is no race condition using global python variable

Tags: python, multithreading, race-condition

I have the following code:

```
from threading import Thread, Lock

value = 0

def adder(amount, repeats):
    global value
    for _ in range(repeats):
        value += amount
 
def subtractor(amount, repeats):
    global value
    for _ in range(repeats):
        value -= amount

def main():
    value = 0

    adder_thread = Thread(target=adder, args=(100, 1000000))
    subtractor_thread = Thread(target=subtractor, args=(100, 1000000))

    subtractor_thread.start()
    adder_thread.start()

    print('Waiting for threads to finish...')

    adder_thread.join()
    subtractor_thread.join()

    print(f'Value: {value}')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

What I don't understand is why I do not have a race condition here? We have global variable, two threads, it suppose to give different values when subtracting and adding, but for me it's always giving 0. How to make race condition in this example? Is the global variable protected with some synchronisation primitive?

Comment: May be the [GIL](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock)s "fault".

Comment: Because you are printing only the final value the race condition doesn't have any meaning. Add prints to the functions.

Comment: Python as a global lock, the global interpreter lock (GIL), that ensure a variable is modified only by one thread at any given time, so a real race condition is not possible.

Comment: The question is a bit unclear: How would you expect the race condition to behave?

Comment: In C++ it will be a race condition here. I would expect to have random output value all the time as in C++.

Comment: Please also share the source of your questions: https://superfastpython.com/thread-race-condition-shared-variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your code can create race condition.
but the `value` that you are printing is zero because of this line.

```py
def main():
    value = 0
```

you declare a `value` in main which you try to print and it won't access the global one.
try this:

```py
def main():
    global value
    value = 0
```

Comment: Yes, that was the mistake, thanks.

Comment: glad to help.happens to the best of us.